# How to order by index in a loop with a vector of dataframe(datatable) colnames?

Tags: r

My code works well when I put the name of the column. But when I want to create a loop with a vector of column names and order the dataframe by indexing the column is not working properly.

Code below works well:

```
indexROW <- round(nrow(Home_strategy_Yes) * 0.2)
Home_strategy_Yes_reordered <- Home_strategy_Yes[order(HT.av.points)]
Home_strategy_Yes_reordered$ID <- seq.int(nrow(Home_strategy_Yes_reordered))
value <- Home_strategy_Yes_reordered[indexROW,HT.av.points]
percentageTOfilter <- min(Home_strategy_Yes_reordered[HT.av.points == value,ID]) -1
valueTOfilter <- Home_strategy_Yes_reordered[percentageTOfilter,HT.av.points]
```

Problem when looping with vector of colnames

```
columns_setA <- c("HT.av.points","HT_av.PointsTotal")
for (i in 1:length(columns_setA)){
  indexROW <- round(nrow(Home_strategy_Yes) * 0.2)
  Home_strategy_Yes_reordered <- Home_strategy_Yes[order(columns_setA[i])]
  Home_strategy_Yes_reordered$ID <- seq.int(nrow(Home_strategy_Yes_reordered))
  value <- Home_strategy_Yes_reordered[indexROW,columns_setA[i]]
  percentageTOfilter <- min(Home_strategy_Yes_reordered[columns_setA[i] == value,ID]) -1
  valueTOfilter <- Home_strategy_Yes_reordered[percentageTOfilter,columns_setA[i]]

}
```

The order function does not work inside the loop as it does outside the loop.

Comment: How about changing your i to go over the different elements like this:
for (i in 1:length(columns_setA)
and then refer to the column names as:
Home_strategy_Yes_reordered[columns_setA[i] == value,ID])

Comment: Thanks. It recognizes the index but Home_strategy_Yes[order(columns_setA[i])] does not work like out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The `i` is not evaluated.   We may need either `get` or convert to `symbol` and `eval`uate inside the loop

```
...
percentageTOfilter <- min(Home_strategy_Yes_reordered[get(i) == value,ID]) -1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding get() order function works  as expected.

```
for (i in 1:length(columns_setA)){
  indexROW <- round(nrow(Home_strategy_Yes) * 0.2)
  Home_strategy_Yes_reordered <- Home_strategy_Yes[order(get(columns_setA[i]))]
  Home_strategy_Yes_reordered$ID <- seq.int(nrow(Home_strategy_Yes_reordered))
  value <- Home_strategy_Yes_reordered[indexROW,get(columns_setA[i])]
  percentageTOfilter <- min(Home_strategy_Yes_reordered[get(columns_setA[i]) == value,ID]) -1
  valueTOfilter <- Home_strategy_Yes_reordered[percentageTOfilter,get(columns_setA[i])]

}
```